# questions about virtual function in c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

I am a beginner of C++, I am studying virtual functions these days.
There are some questions confuse me a lot.

for example:

```
class A {
  public:
  virtual void f() {
      //do something; 
  }
}

class B: public A {
   public:
   virtual void f() {
//do something;
}
}
```

1. `class A` contains a virtual function `f()`, and `class B` inherits it. Inside `class B`, the function `f()` is also declared as virtual, so does this mean `f()` in `class B` overloads `f()` in `class A`? Does it allow classes which inherit `B` to overload `f()`? Or does `B` define a new virtual function which is different from `f()` in `class A`?
2. Virtual functions provide a way of overloading methods. If `B` inherits `A` and does not declare the `f()` as `virtual`, then can a class `C` which inherits `B` overload the `f()` and achieve polymorphism?

Comment: Look how much easier to read your question is now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> inside class B, the function f() also be declared as virtual, so does this mean f() in class B overload f() in class A

No, it doesn't *overload*. It *overrides*. Also the keyword `virtual` is optional in class `B`. `B::f()` will always be a `virtual` function, whether you write `virtual` or not.

The term *overload* is used when you define a function with *same* name but *different* parameter(s).  In your case, the signature of the function `f` is exactly same in both classes, that means it isn't *overloading*; the derived class basically *overrides* the base class definition of `f()`.

Comment: How else can you `override` a function, without using `virtual`?

Comment: @Als: See this : http://www.ideone.com/4MIRs ... that is overriding. As I said, `virtual` keyword only enables *dynamic dispatching* of the function (runtime polymorphism).

Comment: Virtual is required for overriding by definition, per §10.3p2 in C++03.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual keyword allows you to ***override*** functions not ***overload*** them.

Also, the virtual attribute is inherited so virtual keyword is optional for `f()` in `class B`.

Comment: `virtual` keyword has nothing to do with overriding. `virtual` has to do with the dynamic dispatching of the function.

Comment: @Nawaz:How else can you `override` functions without using `virtual`?

Comment: @Nawaz: And how is that piece of code related to overloading or overidding? Overriding is specifically for polymorphic classes!

Comment: @Als: What is that then? (Also, it's not related to overloading, it's overriding). And No, overriding is not specifically for polymorphic classes. It only means you're providing another definition of the function inherited from base class.

Comment: @Nawaz: It is neither, overloading nor overriding.

Comment: @Nawaz: 1. Your classes are not even related in that source example & Yes Overriding is specifically for polymorphic classes.

Comment: @Als: What is that then? Can you call the `A::f` using instance of `B`?

Comment: @Als: Overriding has NOTHING to do with polymorphism!

Comment: @Als: Alright, that was typo, here is the fixed version : http://www.ideone.com/4MIRs

Comment: @Nawaz: Have you posted the correct link? Because I dont see any relation between your `struct A` and `struct B`. Since they dont share any relationship...You can never call `A::f()` using instance of `B`

Comment: @nawaz: Since now you posted the correct link. This is still not overloading or overriding. It is `function hiding`. The derived struct version `B::f()` hides the base struct version `A::f()`

Comment: @Als:  If its function hiding, then can you unhide it?  In case of function hiding, the programmer can unhide it by writing `using A::f` in the derived class, but in this case, you cannot, since its not function hiding in the first place.

Comment: @Nawaz: Check this http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9

Comment: @Als: That is function hiding, because both functions has different signature (the parameter type is different). That case is different from the case I presented.

Comment: @Nawaz: I had asked this specific Q here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406533/overloading-vs-overidding the reponses told me its hiding not overloading nor overidding

Comment: @Als: The accepted answer is wrong (@Space_C0wb0y got it wrong, you there Space? )

Comment: @Nawas: C++98 10.3/2 "If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member function vf with the same name and smae parameter list as Base::vf is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual an it _overrides_ Base::vf."

Comment: @Nawas: overrides is in italic in this citation, meaning it is a definition of override.

Comment: @Nawaz: Ay thoughts about the quote from the Standard. Just bumping this to draw your attention since AProgrammer didnt spell your name correctly.

Comment: @AProgrammer and @Als:  The quotation doesn't say that the term *override* is used only with `virtual` function. Override simply means Replacement which is what is happening even if the function is not virtual.

Comment: @Nawaz, could you point me to one place in the standard where override is use for something else? I found none, and I also note that C++0X is introducing a keyword override in order to check that a declaration is overriding a virtual member.

Comment: @Nawaz: Als is right, using the terms as the C++ standard defines them.  Colloquially, "overrides" and "overloads" may be used differently, but C++ has specific meanings for both.  Overriding requires a virtual.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a function virtual what you are really saying to the compiler is that you want this function to behave in a polymorphic manner.  That is, from your example if we have the following:

```
A* foo = new B();
foo->f();
```

it will call B's "f" function and not A's "f" function.  To take it further, if we have a C which inherits from B like you've said:

```
class C : public B{}

B* foo = new C();
foo->f():
```

this calls B's "f".  If you had defined it within C, it would have called C's method.

To explain the different behavior between virtual and non-virtual let's take this example:

```
struct Foo{
    virtual void f();
    void g();
};

struct Bar{
    virtual void f();
    void g();
};

Foo* var = new Bar();
var->f(); //calls Bar's f
var->g(); //calls Foo's g, it's not virtual
```

make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Since A::f is virtual, and B::f has the same *signature*, it is said that B::f *overrides* A::f.

Which means:

```
A * p = new B;
p->f(); // invokes B::f
```

EDIT: The following is just plain wrong (see the comments):

<strike>Since B::f is also virtual, then it would be possible for a child class of B to override it again. If B:f wasn't virtual, than any method with the same signature in a child class would simply shadow it (that is, it would be a different method).</strike>

So, the behaviors depends on the parent.

Comment: Not entirely correct. You don't need to have virtual keyword in Class B to make it overridable in class C (derived from B). virtual in class B is optional and the only reason of it being there is to have some verbosity.

Comment: `B::f()` will always be virtual, the `virtual` keyword in `B` is optional. since `f` was declared virtual in `A`, all classes deriving form `A` or `B` can override `f`, even if `virtual` is not explicitly mentioned in `B`.

Comment: @sth: Even if `f` was not declared virtual, all classes derived from `A` can override it.