# Function Overloading oop

Tags: function, oop, overloading

Is Function Overloading is same as function overriding as can we implement in  Dervived class ???

Can we called this also a function overloading

```
class Base {
public:
    void display(int a) {

        cout << "Base class";
    }
};
class dervived :public Base {
public:
    void display(int a,int b)
    {
        Base::display(6);
    //  cout << "Devived Class";
    }
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5911765/62576 is a good explanation of the differences between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly recommend reading up on static vs dynamic polymorphism.  But to answer your question:

Overloading is an example of static polymorphism, aka polymorphism that occurs at compile time.  When you overload methods, the compiler will internally map them as separate function calls, and in the final binary, it's no different to naming the overloaded functions different things.

Overriding is an example of dynamic polymorphism, aka polymorphism that occurs at run time.  When you override a method, it actually replaces the method that is overridden when the object is instantiated.

This is most apparent if you create a subclass of the object; said subclass will have access to both overloaded methods, but only the override method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no unanimous agreement on what exactly is OOP. However, broadly speaking, OOP requires *dynamic* (or "late") binding: an operation is dispatched according to the run-time type of an object (or multiple objects, under multiple dispatch).

Function overloading, as embodied in, for example, C++, is *static*; what target is invoked by any given function call is resolved by the compiler prior to run-time, based on static type information. It is a form of static polymorphism.

Early/static binding can only replace late/dynamic binding in situations where the compiler knows the exact type of the objects that are involved.

If that can be done everywhere in the program, then, arguably, no part of it is actually object-oriented.